# How do I set a starting value in a react hook form Controller

Tags: material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm using React Hook Form with Material UI. I would like to know how to setup the initial value of my MUI radio button. Right now I'm able to select the initial value but it doesn't set the form value, I always get undefined unless I select the second option and comeback to my initial value. Here's a quick exemple of my radio buttons in CodeSandBox.

[image: Edit dreamy-jang-m30n4g]

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not providing `defaultValue` when using `controller`. Please check `defaultValue` section on https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller/ .
To solve your problem, please update code with following sample, this has been tested in your provided codesandbox and working fine. Let me know, if you stuck with the solution or if its not working for you.

```
...
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string>("cyber");

  const defaultValues = {
    type: value,
  };

  const methods = useForm({
    defaultValues,
    mode: "onSubmit",
  });
...
```

Comment: I managed to make it work a minute before your post. But thank you that exactly what was the proble. I thought that the defaultValue was use only when you have an uncontrolled component. 

Here's the modified version of my code if anyone is interested : https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-jang-m30n4g?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/App.tsx